# Zooming an object based on mouse position

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got a large large Sprite, and I want to zoom in and out keeping mouse position as the pivot point, exactly how google maps or the photoshop zoom works, when you rotate the mouse wheel.

To archieve the zoom effect I tween the scaleX and scaleY properties, but the fixed point is (0,0), while i need to be the mouse position (that changes everytime, of course).

How can I change this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out by searching the right words on google ...
This link explains the Affine Transformations http://gasi.ch/blog/zooming-in-flash-flex/
 and so I can Tween the transformation Matrix:

```
var affineTransform:Matrix = board.transform.matrix;
affineTransform.translate( -mouseX, -mouseY );
affineTransform.scale( 0.8, 0.8 );
affineTransform.translate( mouseX, mouseY );
var originalMatrix:Matrix = board.transform.matrix;
TweenLite.to(originalMatrix, 0.7, {a:affineTransform.a, b:affineTransform.b, c:affineTransform.c, d:affineTransform.d, tx:affineTransform.tx, ty:affineTransform.ty, onUpdate:applyMatrix, onUpdateParams:[originalMatrix]});
```

:-)

Answer (score 2):

I just did a [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enGB326GB326&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=zoom+about+an+arbitrary+point) for "zoom about an arbitrary point" (minus the quotes) and the first result looks promising.

You have to take the original offset out the scale and then reapply it at the new scale. I've done this myself but don't have the code to hand right now, so I'll see if I can dig it out and post it later.

The pseudo code for this is something like this (from memory):

```
float dir = UP ? 1 : -1;
float oldXscale = Xscale;
float oldYscale = Yscale;
Xscale += dir * increment;
Yscale += dir * increment;
newX = (oldX - Xoffset) / Xscale;
newY = (oldY - Yoffset) / Yscale;
Xoffset += (newX * oldXscale) - (newX * Xscale);
Yoffset += (newY * oldYscale) - (newY * Yscale);
```

Anything not declared is a "global"

Comment: Yeah, but since i'm tweening, i can't just 'move' the sprite when the tween ends..

i can tween the x and y also, but tweening 4 properties of a complex object start to seem to me too much (but maybe i'm wrong.. i have to try)

Comment: Well this is the basis of what you'd do if you were tweening manually, so can you set the ends of the tween from this?

Comment: By tweening manually means on enterframe or during the event callback itself. val += (cur - target) / delta

Answer (score -1):

```
private static function onMouseWheel(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var zoomAmount:Number = 0.03;

    if (event.delta < 0)
        zoomAmount *= -1;

    var x:int = largeLargeSprite.mouseX;
    var y:int = largeLargeSprite.mouseY;
    largeLargeSprite.scaleX += zoomAmount;
    largeLargeSprite.scaleY += zoomAmount;
    largeLargeSprite.x -= x * zoomAmount;
    largeLargeSprite.y -= y * zoomAmount;
}
```